GitHub Action has stopped to schedule the workflow that was successfully running for 6 months
My GitHub Action workflow has the following triggers:

workflow dispatch;
schedule using a cron expression: "0 12 * * 1,2,4".

It was scheduling the workflow for about 6 months, but it just stopped doing so a few weeks ago.
I'm still able to run it manually using the dispatch.
I tried to change the last committer to the workflow, but it didn't help.
The runner is macos-latest (if it matters).

As per docs

High load times include the start of every hour. If the load is sufficiently high enough, some queued jobs may be dropped. To decrease the chance of delay, schedule your workflow to run at a different time of the hour.

Try changing first 0 to another number.

I'll try to re-schedule to 30 12, thanks. Will keep this thread updated.
